# Determine the probability that $X+Y\leq 3$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random losses with joint density function

$$f(x,y)=\frac{{e}^{-9}{7}^{x}{2}^{y}}{x{!}y{!}}$$

for $x$ and $y$ non-negative integers What is the probability that $X+Y \leq 3\text{?}$

Is there an easier way than going about it with integration? If I have to use integration, how would I even find the limits? I can't say I can draw that graph without a calculator, unless I'm given 20 or so minutes solely for that.

Comment: Hint: convolution.

Comment: @SeanRoberson is this two poissons?

Comment: What's the support?

Comment: $P(X=0,Y=3)+P(X=1,Y=2)+P(X=2,Y=1)+P(X=3,Y=0)+P(X=0,Y=0)?$ @PMF

Comment: @ACoc "*for $x$ and $y$ non-negative* **integers**" so "integration" isn't really valid here (*unless you are being pedantic and calling just summing up a few finite numbers "integration"*).  As for $P(X=0,Y=3)+\dots + P(X=0,Y=0)$ you only added the cases where $X+Y=3$ and $X+Y=0$.  You have not yet added the cases where $X+Y=2$ and $X+Y=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the joint distribution is the product of two Poisson distributions -

\begin{align*}
f(x, y) &= \frac{e^{-9}7^x 2^y}{x! y!} \\
&= \frac{e^{-7} 7^x}{x!} \frac{e^{-2} 2^y}{y!} \\
&= f_X(x) f_Y(y)
\end{align*}

As the joint PMF can be written as a product of marginal PMFs, the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and the sum of two independent Poisson variables is Poisson with parameter equal to the sum of the two parameters. Hence, $X+Y$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda = 9$.

Let $Z = X+Y$. We can then compute $P(Z \leq 3)$, which is (check this) $0.02122$.